# C++/OpenCV - How can i get my image after using flann::index? (With BoF)

Tags: c++, opencv, matching, flann

I use BoW with SURF and FlannBasedMatcher for image retrieval inside a database. 
I extracted all my features of my database (Training) using SURF , then i builded the vocabulary and finally i got the BOF frequency histograms for each pictures inside my database (training).

to be clear, i don't put the details of all of this process but tell me if you need some details.

So at this step i have :

- **cv::Mat allDescriptors**   --> descriptors of my all database (training)
- **cv::Mat Vocabulary**  --> codebook representation
- **cv::Mat responseDatabase** -->  frequency histograms for each pictures inside my database

Then i used a query and compute its reponse according to the vocabulary computed just before.
Finally i have this data :

- **cv::Mat responseQuery** --> frequency histogram of my query

Now i have some difficulties.
I used

```
 cv::flann::Index flannIndex(responseDatabase, cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN);
cv::Mat results, dists;
int k=2;
flannIndex.knnSearch(responseQuery, results, dists, k, cv::flann::SearchParams() );
```

It worked well and i got this results :

- cv::Mat results -->  [38, 117]
  -
- cv::Mat dist --> [0.0010655867, 0.013091294]

But now with those results, how can i recover the two pictures corresponding to my 2 nearest neighbors ? 
Indeed, i don't have any trace of the pictures inside each of my data.

Maybe, i missed one step but which one ?

Thank

Comment: How is responseQuery initialized? Need more code. Anyway, my guess is the indices in results should match your image database indices in some way, if not exactly. Hence, image 38 should be the closest match to your query point.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but i don't know if it was the best way.

After the computation of each image like that :

```
bowide.compute(img,keypoints,responseHist);
```

i saved the pictures in a big vector and therefore, i can load them for the matching.

```
  vectorImg.push_back(img);
```

The problem is, i have to save the name of each picture in a txt file and then read the txt file during the matching. (in order to load them)
Indeed the computation of BoWFeature for each image in the database is done only one time and i don't want to run the same process each time i would like to compare a query with the database. So that once my database is trained, i can only do a matching because i have in a txt file the all my picture with an index.